# How to setup WCF

Tags: wcf

I went through many posts but, i did not able to clear my some of basic doubts related to WCF service as follow:

1. Why should we keep separate class library projects assembly for `Service.Contracts` and `Service.Implementation` ?
   we can implement one interface multiple times even it in single assembly.
   It suppose to create - WCF Application project and maintain interfaces into separate folder and SVC.cs file separately.
2. Add service reference is not good option as it adds all the schemas into client side.
   svcutil.exe is also do same thing. Then, what is the best way to consume wcf service at client side ?

Answer (score 1):

All is explained in this great article - [WCF the Manual Way…the Right Way](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39837).

Essentially, **Add Service Reference** and **svcutil** just lead to client proxies that become out of date over time; and the fact that the solution has multiple types defined for what are essentially the same class.

**Update**: Since writing this answer I have learnt not to *have answers in another castle* so I update below:

Essentially, *WCF the Manual Way…the Right Way* describes that rather than using **Add Service Reference**, you instead divide your WCF system into **separate dlls** for:

1. Contracts
2. Service implementation
3. Roll-your-own client proxies

Both the **service and client** add normal code references (not service references) to the **contracts dll**.

In this way, the service and client are using the same types (and not code-generated ones in the client) and when the contract changes - both the service and client are forced to update less a compile error appears.  No more out-of-date clients.