# How do you supply a type that's defined in a web service to another web service (share types)?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I've got 2 WCF services. Service A contains the definition of the type MyEntity. Service B contains a service reference to Service A and therefore can use the type for MyEntity. So I have a method that looks like this:

```
protected void Update (ServiceA.MyEntity entity)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Now I want to use this method in Service A, so I added a service reference for Service B and tried:

```
protected UpdateServiceB(MyEntity entity)
{
    using(ServiceB.ServiceClient client =  new ServiceB.ServiceClient())
    {
        client.Update(entity);
    }
}
```

This didn't work and complained that the types were not the same, even though Service B is using the type defined in Service A. How can I solve this?

***UPDATE***

I avoided the issue due to time constraints and passed the Guid of MyEntity from Service A to Service B instead. I then used an existing method called 'GetMyEntity(Guid entityId)' in Service A to retrieve the entity in Service B:

```
protected void Update (Guid entityId)
{
    MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();        

    using (ServiceAClient client = new ServiceAClient())
    {
        entity = client.GetMyEntity(entityId);
    }

    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are using service references by way of Visual Studio's **Add Service Reference** command.  While adequate, it can arguably become troublesome in medium to large projects due to:

1. Service types are **re-defined in the client** rather than using a common library (as you have discovered).
2. When a service contract changes, this will generally cause the service to be updated but not so in the client because of point 1.  Client proxies become stale overtime as the schema evolves.  You have to **refresh reference**

My best suggestion is **not** to use **Add Service Reference** and roll your client proxies by hand.

Once performed you will have additional libraries:

1. **A.Contracts.dll** - here you define all the service interfaces and data models for service A
2. **B.Contracts.dll** - here you define all the service interfaces and data models for service B
3. **Common.Contracts.dll** - If A & B have common types, place them here. (canonical data models)
4. **A.Service.dll** - service A implementation
5. **B.Serivce.dll** - service B implementation
6. **ClientProxies.dll** - roll-your-own client proxies for all your services

You don't have to implement all of the above now.  All that is required is the manual **ClientProxies.dll** and you can always iterate to the rest later as required.

### More

- [Tell me more about WCF the Right Way in my other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353801/how-to-setup-wcf/24360776#24360776)

Comment: +1. A lot better - as otherwise you add redundant info and it is really inconvenient to regenerate the references on any change in the contracts while you actively develop them.

Comment: I'll have a read of the article referenced in your link. However, in point 2 you say I need to refresh my reference. I've literally just added them, so nothing will have changed in the service contracts and therefore making them become stale. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @sr28 Your references should be up to date yes, but in your case I suspect **Service A** has 2 definitions of `MyEntity` - one that _it_ defines and another in the auto-generated client proxy code for invoking **Service B**.  Hence the _"...complained that the types were not the same"_.  Cure is to not use codegen proxies

Comment: It's a very interesting article and something I will certainly consider for future services. I particularly liked the ability to alter the hosting without any implications for the service itself. However, time isn't on my side for this and to start playing with a method I'm not familiar with would be madness. Would I be able to fix with simply creating a proxy and using that rather than using 'Add Service Reference'?

Comment: Certainly. At minimum, a new manual proxy is perhaps all that is required giving you the freedom to iterate later if you wish to that described in the article.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as, after more research, seems to be the best way to handle it. Thanks for your help.