# Passing an object list from a wcf service to an asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, service

I communicate between a windows service and an asp.net web application through a WCF service. For example: I pass data from the windows service to the wcf service and then to the web application. Works with strings, ints, and longs but I can't pass a list of objects.

Is there a proper way of doing that?

**asp.net web application**

*Action*

```
WcfService.ServiceClient1 client = new WcfService.ServiceClient1("BasicHttpBinding_IService1");
ViewBag.s  = client.GetDiretorySize("something").ToString();
```

**Wcf Service**

*IService1*

```
[OperationContract]
List<Objects> GetDirectorySize(string path);
```

*Service1*

```
public List<Objects> GetDirectorySize(string path)
{
    List<Objects> size = dh.GetSize(path);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: I have a wcf service and an asp.net web application which is the client. My windows service is referenced to the wcf service. Then I call a method in the wcf service from the web application that calls the method in the running service.

Comment: Can you show your code for the method in your WCF service and the call your app makes to this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the classes you're passing around are defined in the WCF service's interface (default IService1.cs). Also make sure that the class is defined as an DataContract and DataMember

For example

```
[DataContract]
class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    string MyString { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: The classes are defined in my windows service which is referenced in the wcf service. Is there an easy way to take them over into the wcf service?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether you've tried this but give this a go:

```
[OperationContract]
List<object> GetDirectorySize(string path);
```

Then change the method to:

```
public List<object> GetDirectorySize(string path)
{
    List<object> MyList = new List<object>();
    //Add items to your list...
    return MyList;
}
```

Comment: so I would add the items in the wcf service ?

Comment: @Duck - well that depends on what you're trying to do. You simply said that it works with strings, ints and longs but not lists. I'm assuming the code you have shown refers to this. So I've altered it so that it will now return you a list. If you explain what you are generally trying to do I might be able to help further.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do but the List comes from an windows service which is referenced in the wcf service. Wait I will edit my post. Imagine that Getsize returns a list of objects. dh.GetSize would be a method in my windows service.

Comment: @Duck - so your trying to return a list of objects to your app that's returned by GetSize in your windows service? Why not simply reference your windows service in your app rather than using the WCF service to return them?

Comment: Because this causes trouble when the service is actively runing.

Comment: Why would a call from your WCF service not 'cause trouble'?

Comment: I have to pass data back from the asp.net web application to the windows service.

Comment: @Duck - so what's not working then? You edited your question but you need to return size.

Comment: As far as I have read about windows services you can't communicate directly with a web app when the service is running. You have to use wcf for it. Now I am looking how I can add the DataContract to the class objetc which is in the windows service.

Comment: @Duck - take look here: http://blog.mikejmcguire.com/2014/05/19/creating-a-wcf-enabled-windows-service/ the windows service hosts the WCF part as well.

Comment: thanks for this tutorial. My situation looks quite similar but I have 2 windows services. One windows service that includes nearly everything what I am doing lets call it "winService1" and one that hosts the wcf service "wcfhost". My problem is what plusheen mentioned in his answer. I am passing a listof objects to my wcf service `list<objects>` but the class in which `objects` are defined is in the "WinService1". I need to know how I can add the DataContract to that external class.

Comment: @Duck - I had a similar question, but passing a type between WCF services. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865841/how-do-you-supply-a-type-thats-defined-in-a-web-service-to-another-web-service the marked answer seems to be the best way to deal with these issues.

Comment: Is there an other way? Is it for example possible doing it with Data Contract Surrogate ?